# Regex to parse a comma-separated list excluding content within parentheses

Tags: ruby, regex

In Ruby:

Given the following example string:

```
str = 'foo,baz(some,other,stuff),hello,goodbye'
```

I would like to parse the string such that the commas appearing with the parens are not considered to be delimiters. So the following fields would be captured given this example:

1. foo
2. baz(some,other,stuff)
3. hello
4. goodbye

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Note that it is impossible (in the strict mathematical sense!) to handle _nested_ parentheses using regular expressions. http://stackoverflow.com/a/133684/239816

Comment: @PaulCantrell: what is commonly called "regular expression" or "regex" is different of what is called "regular expression" in computer science, and this tool doesn't have this kind of limitations (in particular in ruby).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: You’re right: since the questioner did specify Ruby, which I didn’t notice at first, they can use the `\g` extension.

Comment: Your example string needs to be bracketed by single or double quotes. Everybody knows what you mean, of course, but you should know that some will downvote for such an omission.  Also, whenever you give an example it's helpful to assign each input object to a variable (e.g., `str = "foo,...goodbye"`). That way, readers can refer to the variables (`str`) in answers and comments without having to define them.

Comment: If you found either answer helpful please consider selecting one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex

```
[^,(]*(?:\([^)]*\))*[^,]*
```

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/eA8mX2/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: This seems to work in that it matches the pattern.  However, I'm having trouble defining the capture groups such that I can capture the fields (as mentioned in my original post)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-regex solution that makes use of Ruby's little-used [flip-flop operator](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop):

```
str = "foo,baz(some,other,stuff),hello,goodbye"

str.split(',').chunk { |s| s.include?('(') .. s.include?(')') ? true : false }.
               flat_map { |tf, a| tf ? a.join(' ') : a }
  #=> ["foo", "baz(some", "other", "stuff)", "hello", "goodbye"]
```

The steps:

```
arr = str.split(',')
  #=> ["foo", "baz(some", "other", "stuff)", "hello", "goodbye"] 

enum = arr.chunk { |s| s.include?('(') .. s.include?(')') ? true : false }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fdf9d01d2e8>:each>
```

Aside: the `flip-flop` operator must be within an `if` statement, so this cannot be simplified to:

```
enum = arr.chunk { |s| s.include?('(') .. s.include?(')') }
```

We can convert this enumerator to an array to see the values it will pass on to [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map):

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[false, ["foo"]], [true, ["baz(some", "other", "stuff)"]],
  #    [false, ["hello", "goodbye"]]]
```

Lastly:

```
enum.flat_map { |tf, a| tf ? a.join(' ') : a }
  #=> ["foo", "baz(some", "other", "stuff)", "hello", "goodbye"]
```